# How to: Correctly reference a Text UI component in a script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

Working on getting familiar with C# and unity development. Today I am working on getting a reference to a Text UI object in my script. The following code below produces this error:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
handle.Awake () (at Assets/handle.cs:20)
```

Script looks like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using playPORTAL.Profile;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class handle : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Text myText;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    void Awake()
    {
        myText.text = "@organickoala718" ;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

What needs improving to correctly get a reference to the Text UI element?

Comment: This error is usually caused by forgetting to assign the GameObject in the inspector. Have you drag/dropped your text UI GameObject onto the "My Text" field in your inspector for the handle component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general: The same way as with any other Component.

Either reference it via the Inspector or use [`GetComponent`](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/getcomponent#5c8a65d5edbc2a001f47d6e6)(Tutorial) or one of its variations.

---

So if that `Text` Component is attached to the same GameObject as your script then you could use [`GetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html)(API) to get the reference on runtime

```
private void Awake ()
{
    if(!myText) myText = GetComponent<Text>();
    myText.text = "@organickoala718" ;
}
```

Also checkout [Controlling GameObjects with Components](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ControllingGameObjectsComponents.html)

---

Btw you should remove the empty methods `Start` and `Update` entirely. They are called by the Unity Engine as messages if they exist so the don't need to exist and only cause unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 2):

You need to either set the `myText` value of your `handle` instance from another script, or set it in the Unity Editor's Inspector window, when you've selected a GameObject that has your `handle` component added.

Answer (score 2):

You need to drag the object you are referencing to from the Unity editor, in the scene, to the script itself.
First attach the script you made to a GameObject in the Unity Scene.
Then drag the "text" component to the Script you recently attached to the GameObject

That would solve the problem you have.

---

Another approach would be to declare a

**public GameObject UITextElement;**

Instead of a public text as you did.
Do the same as i wrote before and in the script write:

**UITextElement.GetComponent().text = "Write your text here!";**